# List saved in ViewBag is printing data in the cshtml View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, view

I saved a list in `ViewBag.FY` from the controller. During debugging it it is showing data in the ViewBag.

When I am printing the data in the view, it is not printing data.

Here is the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC4_Theming.HRMS_Tax>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var taxSlabsByFinancialYear = ViewBag.FY;
}

            <div class="table table-responsive">
                <table id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped  table-bordered" cellspacing="0">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Min-Range</th>
                            <th>Max-Range</th>
                            <th>Annual-Range</th>
                            <th>Fix-Amount</th>
                            <th>(%)-Amount</th>
                            <th>Year-Slab</th>
                            <th>IsActive</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>

                        @{
                            if (ViewBag.FY == null)
                            {
                                <p>Please Select Financial Year</p>
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                int a = 0;
                                foreach (var item in ViewBag.FY)
                                {
                                    a++;
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@a</td>
                                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                                        <td>@item.MinAmountRang</td>
                                        <td>@item.MaxAmountRang</td>
                                        <td>@item.Anuual_Amount</td>
                                        <td>@item.Fix_Amount</td>
                                        <td>@item.Percentage_Amount</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </thread>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me - who knows an answer to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? Why are you adding the data records to the `thead` node instead of `tbody`? Your closing tag for `thead` has a typo, it says `thread`. Is that the way it is in your code? By the way, you should try to avoid using ViewBag for this. Why not add it to the view model?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class FY
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MinAmountRang { get; set; }
        public int MaxAmountRang { get; set; }
        public int Anuual_Amount { get; set; }
        public int Fix_Amount { get; set; }
        public int Percentage_Amount { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestViewBag()
        {
            ViewBag.FY = new List<FY> { 
                new FY {  Name="n1", MaxAmountRang=10, MinAmountRang=1, Fix_Amount=3, Percentage_Amount=4, Anuual_Amount=5} ,
                new FY {  Name="n2", MaxAmountRang=10, MinAmountRang=1, Fix_Amount=3, Percentage_Amount=4, Anuual_Amount=5} ,
                new FY {  Name="n3", MaxAmountRang=10, MinAmountRang=1, Fix_Amount=3, Percentage_Amount=4, Anuual_Amount=5} ,

            };
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var taxSlabsByFinancialYear = ViewBag.FY;
}

<div class="table table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped  table-bordered" cellspacing="0">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Min-Range</th>
                <th>Max-Range</th>
                <th>Annual-Range</th>
                <th>Fix-Amount</th>
                <th>(%)-Amount</th>
                <th>Year-Slab</th>
                <th>IsActive</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
    
           
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                if (ViewBag.FY == null)
                {
                    <p>Please Select Financial Year</p>
                }

                else
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.FY)
                    {
                        a++;
                        <tr>
                            <td>@a</td>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                            <td>@item.MinAmountRang</td>
                            <td>@item.MaxAmountRang</td>
                            <td>@item.Anuual_Amount</td>
                            <td>@item.Fix_Amount</td>
                            <td>@item.Percentage_Amount</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this, you should Cast the ViewBag Data0 to a list

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC4_Theming.HRMS_Tax>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        var taxSlabsByFinancialYear = (**YourListName**)ViewBag.FY; 
    }
```